# VB.NET - Counting how many folders in a specific directory

Tags: vb.net

What would be a suitable way to count how many folders are in a specific directory (not counting sub-folders or files within those folders, just the count of the folders in the specified directory).

I have looked around the Internet but could not find a suitable example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's as simple as this

```
Dim folderCount As Integer = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("c:\your_direcrory").Count()
```